# Selection Box overlapping Dropdown

Tags: html, css

I am having issues of getting the following selection boxes to appear correctly. When you select like "Package" the dropdown menu is behind the "template" selection box.

I have tried many things to try and get the dropbox to be above the selection box, but nothing seems to work.

[website](https://www.koolbookingsystems.co.uk/order.html)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Could you create a code sample that will replicate the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to resolve the issue by removing the `z-index: 10;` attribute of the .mfSelect class in style.css:3135.

I believe the problem lies in the stacking context of the elements which is affected by more than just the z-index.

Comment: Thank you! That sorted the issue.